# How to copy from an ordinary array to array of structures?

Tags: c

I have this code but it gives me some errors when compiling.

[Error] expected identifier or '(' before '[' token

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//functions
void createdeck();


//structures
typedef struct card{
    int val;
    char face;
    char suit;
}deck[52];

//global variables
const char suits[4] = { 'D', 'C', 'H', 'S' };
const char face[13] = { '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'X', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A' };

int main()
{
    createdeck();
}

void createdeck()
{
    int ctr1,ctr2,count = 0;

    for (ctr1 = 0; ctr1 < 4;ctr1++)
    {
        for (ctr2 = 0;ctr2 < 13; ctr2++)
        {
            deck[count].val = count + 1;
            deck[count].face = face[ctr2];
            deck[count].suit = suit[ctr];
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

[Error] expected identifier or '(' before '[' token
That was what the compiler says

```
deck[count].val = count + 1;
deck[count].face = face[ctr2];
deck[count].suit = suit[ctr];
```

These are the highlighted errors.
Please enlighten me. I am still a beginner.

Comment: Your array is `suits` not `suit`

Comment: `deck` is an type, not variable. Add variable like `deck aDeck;` ... `aDeck[count].val`...

Comment: `suit[ctr]` typo as `suits[ctr1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `deck` is type, not a variable (has no memory initialised for it).

I recommend not using a typedef, as they obfuscate the type and tend to make things more confusing (they're misused quite often), and to just declare a variable named `deck` within your `createdeck()` function, like so:

```
//structures
struct card{
    int val;
    char face;
    char suit;
};

...


void createdeck()
{
    struct card deck[52];
```

Note that you have also mispelled `suits` as `suit` on line

```
deck[count].suit = suit[ctr];
```

And `ctr` on that line does not exist as a variable, as well.

Comment: Wrong because now deck is local to createdeck and gone after createdeck returns.